# couldn't find file hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, test-project

I want to run a test-porject (with the usage of NHibernate).

I configured NH in the app.config.

Why do I get this error?

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\MetadataServiceTest\bin\Debug\hibernate.cfg.xml'.

Comment: take a look at http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/CDV-588 it might helps you

Comment: so you added the hibernate section to app.config? and it's still looking for hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: @dotjoe you are right. I added to the wrong app.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure hibernate.cfg.xml is set as content and copy to output directory.

Comment: the config in web.config is not enough?

Comment: NHibernate can be configured either way, Web/App.config or hibernate.cfg.xml. If you have the settings in the Web.config, then you don't need the hibernate.cfg.xml.